# timer in a thread with pthread in C?

Tags: c, pthreads

in threads, i need to periodically do some work in some different intervals, what would be a good way to do this? With sleep(), then i need keep track of the interval to the next wakeup, which doesn't seem to be the best way.

thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `clock_nanosleep` with the `TIMER_ABSTIME` flag to work with absolute times instead of relative times for your sleep. That will avoid error accumulation problems and race conditions where your program gets interrupted and another process scheduled after getting the current time but before calling sleep.

Alternatively you could use POSIX timers (`timer_create`) with a signal handler, where the signal you choose is blocked in all threads but yours, or with timer delivery in a new thread that signals a condition variable or semaphore your thread is waiting on.

Comment: Thank you! clock_nanosleep seems ideal for a single timer. But my thread has more than one different intervals for different tasks. So I would calculate next wakeup time all the time. timer_create would have been a good option, but i have more than one of these kinds of threads.

Comment: What's wrong with `timer_create`? You can create very many timers with it, up to 32k when I tested it on my system...

Comment: I thought with timer, the signal will be delivered to an arbitrarily selected thread in the process. Maybe I remembered this wrong.

Comment: This is true, but you can either arrange that the chosen signal is blocked in all but one thread, or you can find a way for the signal handler to notify the correct thread (although the latter is difficult to do efficiently because most functions that could do it are not async-signal-safe).

Comment: Okay, I guess I know what you mean. I can either have a timer thread holding a list of sorted future timer tasks or store one such list locally in each of my thread.

Comment: Timers allow you to arrange for the signal handler to receive an argument, so you know which timer the event was associated with.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how much accuracy you need:

- you can use [clock_gettime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) Which is very accurate (~10MHz). (Go with the realtime or monotonic clock)
- If resolution and overhead is not a problem, but instead you would like to get the real-world time you can also you [gettimeofday](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gettimeofday.html)