# How can I check that my thread has ran for 5 seconds?

Tags: c, operating-system, pthreads

I have two pthreads running in my code. They run simultaneously using `usleep()` and I want to run both of them for 5 sec.

How can I check that my thread has run for 5 seconds, so that I can kill the thread after 5 seconds?

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518193/timer-in-a-thread-with-pthread-in-c  I think the first answer could be useful

Comment: Threads cannot be killed; they only exit voluntarily.

Comment: For the record, you should not kill threads.  It can be dangerous and can leave memory unclaimed.  You should notify the thread that it's time to die, and wait for it to kill itself to preserve its honor.

Comment: sleep time is different from dedicated CPU time isn't it? And it's hard to trace the CPU time a process/thread had in total coz one need to trace when it's scheduled/preempted ...